# Embedded linux/android kernel development workflow

Tags: android, c++, git, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I was inspired by this [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856241/git-workflow-for-corporate-linux-kernel-development) question, but I didn't get the whole picture.
I'm developing a kernel and Android system for a new device which is based on a commercial chipset platform.

The chipset vendor provides me with a 'fixed kernel code zipped','android proprietary sources','modem sources'.
All these parts are paired, *E.G.*, I can't change(to some extent) one of the platform elements(kernel,modem,system) without effecting other parts.

It's also quite limiting, what will happen if there is a need for a newer version? I can't be sure i'll get vendor's sources for it.

So here are some flows I made:

=============================================================

**Workflow1: - I don't need newer version, i need release device now!**

1.Download the latest public kernel the chipset provider and his system

2.Add my own drivers into the kernel

3.Add proprietary source into the build

4.compile -> everything is already configured

5.debug -> little

6.patch -> little

7.release -> fast

8.give an update? -> fail!? - i need new kernel/system from chipset vendor.

==================================================================

**Workflow2: I dont need the vendor**

1.Download a clean android system from google/cyanogem etc..

2.Add my drivers to the kernel

3.Get kernel patches from the chipset vendor's sources

3.Build device directory for proprietary files

4.configure/patch the proprietary to compile with the system -> hell

5.face alot of low level bugs -> hell

6.debug/patch

7.miss deadline and get fired

Any idea how this actually works in major mobile device manufacturers?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever seen device manufacturers that are fast at updates? I suppose it is more like workflow2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working for one of chipset vendors. We provide reference kernel and reference android sources for our costumers. But we provide them not as "zipped source", but as git repository, so costumers can see all patches we put in kernel/AFS/etc and merge them into theirs repositories.

So, in your case I recommend you to ask your vendor for access to a git repository. If it is impossible, I reccomend you to use workflow 1. If you need a major update (like switch from GB to ICS), you'll need new vendor's sources anyway. Minor updates can be done on top of existing  sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually my vendor has a public GIT repository but the source I need to take is a specific tag. I'll try that workflow, hope it will be efficient