# How do I setup git with no central repository?

Tags: git

Three of us in the office are on Mac laptops and we use git day to day.

We want to share a repo with each other without setting up a central repo.

Dave pushes to Sally who pushes to Chandu.

Chandu can pull from Sally and Dave.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: no github, no central internal box

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly compatible with the "Decentralized" notion of a DVCS like Git, and very easy to setup (all you need is sharing paths between the repos)

The only issues to address are:

- the workflow of merges you need to follow (how do you manage public branches -- "public" as in pushed/pulled from one repo to another).
  See for instance this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856241/git-workflow-for-corporate-linux-kernel-development/1856474#1856474), or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049917/workflow-description-for-git-usage-for-in-house-development/1050628#1050628).
- the necessity to push to a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830701/how-do-i-check-if-a-repository-is-bare/1830712#1830712)**, meaning each programmer must have two repo: one public where other push to (a bare repo), and one private, cloned of the first, from which he/she can push to other.
  That way you do not need to setup only *one "central* bare repo, but you can truly push to anyone you want.

Comment: And as long as you know that there's a "blessed" repo on Alice's laptop that is the build repo, this is actually what git is for!

Answer (score 1):

Just pull from each other :)

Instead of pushing, just make a pull request (verbally, on IRC, or however you want); ask people to pull from you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to setup a bare remote git repo.
Check instructions here.

http://toolmantim.com/thoughts/setting_up_a_new_remote_git_repository

Comment: The question says "without a central repo"

Comment: hasen: I guess the OP meant one bare git repo, per person ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to push to/pull from each other while offsite, you're going to need some kind of VPN so your laptops can talk to each other.  It might be easier to set up a remote repository (or a set of them, one each) on a server somewhere, because that deals with the laptops being offline when you want to merge.