# How to resolve git merge/rebase conflicts with 2 remote repos?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

Having an issue with git rebase conflict, but only when using 2 remote repos. Here's the workflow:

1. Do work...
2. Commit
3. pull -r staging master

This works fine. If there is a conflict I can resolve it.

Then the problem happens when working with production remote repo. I am the only one pushing to production.

1. git pull -r production (need to do this before pushing to production for some reason...don't know why because it should be a fast forward push.)
2. git push production
3. git pull -r staging (to update my repo)

Here's where I get all sorts of merge conflicts on files I haven't worked on.

The conflict may look like this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
  here's some code...
=======
  more code...
>>>>>>> commit foo
```

So, here are the questions:

1. Why do I need to pull from production when I am the only one pushing to it?
2. Why are there merge conflicts on code that is already committed and I have not changed?
3. Which commit would I choose? HEAD or commit foo
4. What is the better process so it doesn't happen?

Comment: A reason I can think that would require a `pull --rebase` is that you are changing the history on **staging** that was already pushed. (Through `merge`'s or `rebase`'s, for example). Remember those change the checksum's of your commits and then git can't make a fast forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a direct side-effect of your `pull --rebase` done for two separate remote repos: you are rebasing existing local commits on top of a remote HEAD you just fetch, making sure to create a new HEAD SHA1 which wouldn't exist on your second remote repo (`prod` for instance)

You can use `pull --rebase` for commits you have never pushed anywhere, as detailed in "[When should I use git pull --rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472254/when-should-i-use-git-pull-rebase)", when collaborating on the same branch of the same remote repo.

But when you have 2 remotes repos, you should avoid it after the first push, as illustrated in "[When will `git pull --rebase` get me in to trouble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590260/when-will-git-pull-rebase-get-me-in-to-trouble?lq=1)".

Even more details on that topic at "[What git branching models actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621610/what-git-branching-models-actually-work)".

Comment: So I should do `git pull` without rebase on the production repo?

Comment: @BSeven that would be better: in general, `pull --rebase` only if what you are rebasing (your local commits) haven't been already pushed (anywhere)

Comment: `git pull` didn't work. There was a bunch of conflicts. I guess `git push -f` is the only solution...

Comment: @BSeven in the state you currently are, one push - fill could indeed be necessary. However, if you stop using rebases, you shouldn't have that many conflicts in the future, and will avoid any forced push.