# How should I employ a versioning system?

Tags: git, svn, versioning

Ok, so different versions of this question is everywhere, but the more I google it, the more confusing it gets.

So. I am a sole developer of a Content Management System that runs on my Linux server farm on a remote location. It has some 700MB of PHP files kept in a /Atlas/Core hierarchy and 700MB of site files kept in /Atlas/Sites - all media and temporary data is kept outside these locations, so for all intents and purposes, these two locations form the meat of my system.

The Sites directory is unique to this specific location, and needn't be versioned at the same time as the Core directory - basically, as far as I can make out - having these as two repositories is the right way.

I do all my development on my Macs (work Mac, laptop, home Mac etc.) and since my CMS is configured to run on the remote Linux system, setting up the same Apache/MySQL environment on my work environments haven't been a prioroty - it could probably be done, but I don't know if it would be worth it.

So, why versioning at all, then? Well, one is for being able to go back to earlier versions, and second when/if there would be more developers involved.

But how do I do it? Would I have a repository on server X and my live production server is server Y and then I have a "test" environment set up on server Z? So changes are made on Z, pushed to X and then pulled to Y?

I then connect to Z from any Mac, make changes, and check them in the web browser and then push them two steps to the production server? That would obviously be super cumbersome for me, but if there is no other way?

ANy thoughts on how to approach this? What am I doing wrong? And what versioning system should I use?

Comment: Have you experience with any source control system?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are few questions in there, so I'll try to address them all;

> Q1. So, why versioning at all, then?

The 2 reasons you've given are more than enough, but also;

- To have a backup.
- To Tag certain snapshots of your codebase as 'special' - a release, a
  milestone...
- To try something out that might take a long time, and might get
  scrapped. You can commit it to a branch, and if it doesn't work, your
  prod code is untouched.

A better question might be, `is there a good reason not to have version control?` The only one I can come up with is that its an extra few steps in your workflow, but since this pays off 100 fold in the long run, its extra steps you can and should live with.

I recommend using git with an online repository service such as [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [GitHub](https://github.com). I prefer BitBucket - as many free private repos as you need (at time of posting).

> Q2. But how do I do it?
>   Would I have a repository on server X and my live production server is server Y and then I have a "test" environment set up on server Z? So changes are made on Z, pushed to X and then pulled to Y?

What you describe sounds fine, so just:

- Read the [progit book](http://git-scm.com/book).
- Install git on your servers.
- Use either BitBucket or GitHub as `server X`.

> "...push them two steps to the production server?... "is no other way?"

Strictly speaking you don't even need server X. You could just push straight from Y to Z. I wouldn't though, just because I'd prefer to use the concept of a central repository as you described. Every git repo is a full copy of the repository though, so you can just push from Y to Z directly. This link might be useful;

- [deploy-a-project-using-git-push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git-push)

> ANy thoughts on how to approach this? What am I doing wrong? And what
>   versioning system should I use?

I don't think you're doing anything wrong.

As I say above, I recommend git. Mercurial very similar, but I find there is more support available for git. BitBucket and GitHub support both I think.

If you do end up with multiple developers, you will want to change this approach I imagine, and start developing locally. In this event, the following may help:

- [git-branch-strategy-for-small-dev-team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428722/git-branch-strategy-for-small-dev-team)

Note - I too suspect you have files there you don't want to commit, as 700MB for just code is huge. Use the .gitignore file to filter out files you don't need tracked.

Answer (score -1):

I think that Apache/MySQL on your work envs is the best choice. You could have easier development process.

Regarding to a version control, I have only doubt about the size. 700Mb is very large codebase. E.g. the Linux kernel is only about 100Mb was written by thousands people several years. Probably you have a lot of binaries?

Anyway, I would recommend to try git first, but keep in mind, that it works the best on real source code, not binary/autogenerated files. If you could exclude them, it would be great. If you have so great code base, I would also recommend to split it in several small repositories.

Answer (score -1):

First off, with 700MB of source there is something (terribly) wrong. I assume that is not all real source, but there are some database dumps and images in there?

Versioning this whole this with git is rather easy. You don’t need a central server for code at all as long as you are the only dev. Just set up git on your dev system and start versioning. If you want, you can stop there. Stick with your old deployment process and be done with it.

Next step would be add a central repo to that setup. I would personally recommend getting a private github repo for 7$/Month. This way you don’t have to worry about setup or backups and adding new devs to your project is easy as cake. Furthermore you get code review and issue tracking. When you have a central repo you just push your changes there once in a while. Done. The biggest advantage of having a central repo (as long as you are the only dev) is the fact that you have a backup of your code and all its history in a remote location.

If you want to, you can also use git for deployment. I would recommand that. There are multiple tutorials out there on how to do that. I prefer a “push and automatic checkout” setup. Then your workflow is like this: develop, commit, push to webserver. Whether you have a central repo or not does not make any difference.

The versioning system I would recommend is definitely git. Or any other of the decentralized ones, but I only have experience with git.