# Why should I create new branch in git repository?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

If the master is default branch of git repository, why should we create another branch?
What is the benefits of creating new branch?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: There's only one answer for this question and that's 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really a general version control question, and would be equally valid if you were asking about Subversion, Perforce, or any other VCS.

Typically you would want to create a new branch in Git when you want to build a new feature based on the `master` branch, without doing the actual work in `master`.  By using a separate branch for your feature, you can do all your development and testing in a separate place, leaving your stable `master` branch alone.  This would allow other developers to continue working directly in `master` or to allow them to create their own feature branches.

Once you have completed the feature and it has been tested, you can bring this branch back into `master` by using `git merge` or by doing a `git rebase` followed by a fast-forward.

Answer (score 1):

master represents a stable version of your app, so you won't check in incomplete, pending-review code into master.

Check this post:
[Git branch strategy for small dev team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428722/git-branch-strategy-for-small-dev-team)