# Upload laravel5.3 project into github to work with multiple developers

Tags: github, laravel-5.3

i have laravel 5.3 project files in developement phase long way to go on live. now one more developer joined me with this. i want share my project via github version control so that we both work on same project without any conflictions. can anyone help me with this how to do it ?

As of now this is not go to the live server.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you know [git-branching](https://help.github.com/articles/about-branches/)

Also check this

[Git branch strategy for small dev team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428722/git-branch-strategy-for-small-dev-team)